# El input en python me arroja un valor vacío al iniciar una iteración

Tags: python

Tengo un problema con una iteración en Python: resulta que al iniciar el programa, el usuario debe introducir un número, este número será la cantidad de iteraciones que realiza el programa. Al llegar a código de las iteraciones, se pide que el usuario ingrese información en una variable llamada *dato* utilizando el input; cuando ingresan la información por primera vez, el valor inicial es vacío, lo cual afecta el funcionamiento de mi programa: se supone que el programa debe recibir el dato que el usuario ingresa, pero es como si a la variable se le asignara un valor vacío al iniciar la iteración.

Dejo el código por si pueden verificar si lo estoy haciendo mal o hay alguna mejor manera de hacerlo:

```
cantidadRegistros = input()
for x in range(int(cantidadRegistros)):
    dato = input()
    print(dato)
```

Obviamente el programa debe hacer más cosas, pero primero necesito solucionar este problema.

Comment: Lo siento, no te hiciste entender. El único problema que veo es que sobrescribes la variable `dato` en cada iteración. Deberías guardar los valores en una lista. Fuera de eso, no se a lo que te refieres. Intenta [algo como esto](https://www.online-python.com/DAJN1WH7Mu).

Answer (score 3):

Con respecto a tu explicación se entiende poco, pero creo que sé cuál es tu problema.

Dices que tu programa no hace lo esperado porque el valor inicial de dato es vacío y esto no es así, tu programa hace lo esperado, le pasas un número (si le pasas algo que no es número el programa da error, no sé si tenías esto en cuenta) y según la cantidad del número, tú le metes un dato y lo muestra en pantalla. Al no pasarle nada a la función `input()` esta no muestra nada por pantalla para solicitarle al usuario algo, por lo que sí que podría parecer que es algún tipo de error, pero si metes algo, por ejemplo una "a", este te muestra la "a" en la línea siguiente, por el `print()`. Pero estos datos introducidos por el usuario se sobreescriben una y otra vez, quedando guardado solo el último introducido, por lo que si después del `for` haces algo con la variable `dato`, solo utilizará el último elemento introducido por el usuario.

Si lo que tú quieres es guardar todos los datos introducidos para luego poder usarlos o algo, la mejor opción seria mediante una lista que conserve todos los datos.

```py
# Le pedimos al usuario que introduzca un valor, y comprobamos que sea un numero para que el programa no de error en caso de no introducir un numero
str_cantidadRegistros = 'Introduce la cantidad de datos que quieres introducir: '
cantidadRegistros = input(str_cantidadRegistros)
while cantidadRegistros.isnumeric() == False:
    print('El valor introducido tiene que ser numero')
    cantidadRegistros = input(str_cantidadRegistros)

# Inicializamos la lista
datos = []
# Iteramos la cantidad de veces que ha introducido el usuario, y le pedimos que introduzca un dato
for x in range(int(cantidadRegistros)):
    dato = input('Introduce el dato numero ' + str(x+1) + ': ')
    # Guardamos el dato en la lista de datos
    datos.append(dato)

# Printamos los datos introducidos por el usuario
print(datos)
```